# Apex DML operation Delete not allowed on List

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am writing an Apex test.

I am getting a compile error saying `DML operation Delete not allowed on List`

```
AsyncApexJob[] currentAsyncJobs = [SELECT Id FROM AsyncApexJob];
delete currentAsyncJobs;
```

I am trying to delete all the AsyncApexJobs so that I can later check that the correct number of jobs have been enqueued after I have executed the class I am testing. ie.

```
List<AsyncApexJob> asyncJobList = [SELECT Id FROM AsyncApexJob];
System.assertEquals(2, asyncJobList.size(), 'Two jobs should have been enqueued');
```

I can't tell what I am doing wrong. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_delete.htm)

I am using atom editor with mavens mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove a job you must call the system.abortJob(jobId), I dont believe you can just delete the job via DML. jobId needs to be either

> The jobId is the ID associated with either AsyncApexJob or CronTrigger

For your test you can always get the initial number then check that it increased by the amount that you expect if for some reason you cant stop the jobs, but if you are scheduling a job using the Schedulable you should just test the scheduled cron as per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

Comment: Thanks. I did have it as checking the amount it increased by but was trying to see if I could make it more elegant. I'm using System.enqueueJob() to enqueue the job, I'm not sure if it would be advised to use the link you posted or to just check the increased amount?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm has example for queueable apex but in testing the job id is not returned, so you would need to just test the effects of what was supposed to happen after the job is complete it after the Test.stopTest()

Comment: Thanks. The job makes a callout, so there's no data that gets mutated that I can use to test. I will just use the initial number of jobs minus the new number of jobs. I don't think its too much of a concern doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting a compile error saying DML operation Delete not allowed on List

```
List<AsyncApexJob> asynclist = new List<AsyncApexJob>();

asynclist = [ Select id ,Status from AsyncApexJob where Status = 'Queued' or Status='holding'];

for ( AsyncApexJob aJob :  asynclist)
{
System.AbortJob(aJob.Id);
}
delete asynclist;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).